# How to auto-click the QPushButton in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have button in my MainWindow and I want it to get automatically clicked?

```
def Button_Display(self):
    self.button_dis= QPushButton('DISPLAY',self)
    self.button_xxx.resize(100,100)
    self.button_xxx.move(100,100)
    self.button_xxx.clicked.connect(self.on_click_display)

def on_click_display(self): 
    QMessageBox.information(self, 'Hello', 'Hello World!' , QMessageBox.Ok)
```

When I click the the button MessageBox appears, but i want to get automatically clicked.

Comment: sorry its.

button_dis  not  button_xxx

Comment: in general: use `foo_button.animateClick()`

Comment: another way around : `self.button_dis.click()`